# Updating a single value in Firebase with python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a total newbie when it comes to backend. I am working on a very simple webpage that needs one element to be updated every couple minutes or so. I'd like it to make a request to my Firebase database, get a single integer, and change a number on the webpage to that integer.

Right now I am having trouble updating the Firebase with a simple Python program. Here is what my Firebase looks like every time I run my python script: [Click](https://i.gyazo.com/be5e35cd4b59e7de68a086da680adc04.png)

When I run the script, it adds 6 new random variables with the value I'd like to send to Firebase. Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
from firebase import firebase
fb = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myAssignedDomain.com/', None)
Result = fb.post('test/coffee', {'percentage': 40})
```

What do I need to do in order to only change one existing value in Firebase rather than create 6 new random variables?

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: To update the existing data, you'd call `fb.put(...)`

Comment: If you only want to update that specific path `firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myAssignedDomain.com/test/coffee/percentage', None).put(40)`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the help, sorry my level of understanding of Firebase is pretty poor. I tried messing around with your suggestion and wasn't quite able to get it working. [This pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sCFqXJ2B) is the error I keep running into when trying to implement the specific path function you posted above.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can update the value of a particular property in firebase python 1.2 package

```
from firebase import firebase
fb = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myAssignedDomain.com/', None)
fb.put('test/asdf',"count",4) #"path","property_Name",property_Value
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will update the 'percentage' value from your node. Just make sure that the node is writable so your script can modify it.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import json


def update_entry(new_percentage):

    my_data = dict()
    my_data["percentage"] = new_percentage

    json_data = json.dumps(my_data).encode()
    request = urllib.requests.Request("https://<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>.firebaseio.com/test/coffe.json", data=json_data, method="PATCH")

    try:
        loader = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        message = json.loads(e.read())
        print(message["error"])
    else:
        print(loader.read())
```